# ValueError: A BigQuery table or a query must be specified with beam.io.gcp.bigquery.ReadFromBigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm trying to pass a BigQuery table name as a value provider for a apache beam pipeline template. According to [their documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.22.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.ReadFromBigQuery) and this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58513065/13083530), it's possible to pass a value provider to `apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.ReadFromBigQuery`.

So this is the code for my pipeline

```
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    """Define runtime argument"""
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input', type=str)
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--output', type=str)

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)

(p | 'Read from BQ Table' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.ReadFromBigQuery(
             user_options.input
         )
```

When I run the code locally, the command line passes the value for `user_options.input` is `--input projectid.dataset_id.table`

However, I had the error:

```
ValueError: A BigQuery table or a query must be specified
```

I tried:

- Pass `projectid:dataset_id.table`
- use `bigquery.TableReference` -> not possible
- Use `f'`{user_options.input}`'`
- Pass a query -> works when run locally but does not work when I call the template on GCP. Error statement:

  missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.", "errors": [ { "message": "Table name "RuntimeValueProvider(option: input, type: str, default_value: None)" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.", "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } } >

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The `table` argument must be passed by name to `ReadFromBigQuery`.

`BigQuerySource` (deprecated) accepts a `table` as the first argument so you can pass one in by position ([docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySource)). But `ReadFromBigQuery` expects the `gcs_location` as the first argument ([docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySource)). So if you are porting code from using `BigQuerySource` to using `ReadFromBigQuery` and you weren't explicitly passing the table in by name, it will fail with the error you received.

Here are two working examples and one that does not work:

```py
import apache_beam as beam

project_id = 'my_project'
dataset_id = 'my_dataset'
table_id = 'my_table'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = [
        '--temp_location=gs://my_temp_bucket',
    ]
    # This works:
    with beam.Pipeline(argv=args) as pipeline:
        query_results = (
          pipeline
          | 'Read from BigQuery' 
          >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=f"{project_id}:{dataset_id}.{table_id}")
        )
    # So does this:
    with beam.Pipeline(argv=args) as pipeline:
        query_results = (
          pipeline
          | 'Read from BigQuery' 
          >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(table=f"{dataset_id}.{table_id}", project=project_id)
        )
    # But this doesn't work becuase the table argument is not passed in by name.
    # The f"{project_id}:{dataset_id}.{table_id}" string is interpreted as the gcs_location.
    with beam.Pipeline(argv=args) as pipeline:
        query_results = (
          pipeline
          | 'Read from BigQuery'
          >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(f"{project_id}:{dataset_id}.{table_id}")
        )
```